# Displaying a message box after a certain period of time

Tags: c#, wpf

Hie guys, i have no code at the moment but my problem is like this. i want to display a message box after a certain period of time after an event has occurred lets say after an enquiry has been made and this message box seeks to remind the user to check on the delivery status of the enquiry lets say after 5 minutes. Any ideas or alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a function to show your message, then you can use a timer.tick event to show your message at a given interval

```
static System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer myTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

public void DoInquiry()
{
   // do your inquiry stuff
   ////////////////////////

   // Set Timer Interval
   myTimer.Interval = = new TimeSpan(0,5,0); // 5 Minutes
   // Set Timer Event
   myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);

   // Start timer
   myTimer.Start();

}

private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs) {
   ShowMessage("Please check on the status");  
}

protected void ShowMessage(string Message)
{
   System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(Message);
}
```

Comment: This was tagged as WPF, rather than WinForms.

Comment: You are correct Paul, updated sample to use DispatchTimer

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You can use that to check when five minutes have passed then show a MessageBox when appropriate.